# How to develop a content assist like the one of Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, content-assist

I want to develop a content assist for my own IDE like the one that Eclipse offers for java.
My problem is:

How to display the information of a  completion proposal has an HTML text(javadoc in the case of eclipse)?

I know only how to use a string to show the information of a method in content assist:

*new CompletionProposal("catch(a)", index + 1, offset - (index + 1), "catch(a)", img, keyword + " ", null, "Catches an exception a");*

Tks for the time, regards Ramos

Comment: Read the section on the Platform Plug-in Developer Guide on content assist: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Feditors_contentassist.htm

Comment: Tks but i already did, the thing is that i know how to do the way they explain but i want to be able to show the user a content information with links and a proper indentation like the one the Eclipse IDE use in java content assist